# How do I browse the Windows folder in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu recently, and I noticed that every time I try to browse the Windows folder, it says

> Sorry could not display all the contents of "windows":
>   Error when getting information for file "/media/carlbrentson/Windows/Windows/regedit.exe": Input/output error"

Is there a way to view it anyway?

EDIT: I installed Ubuntu as a separate OS, intending not to use Windows ever again, so Windows isn't necessarily bootable, and I'd much rather not format everything to re-install it.

Comment: Welcome! Did you run `chkdsk` from windows?

Comment: Is Ubuntu installed from within WSL? Or, did you install it on your PC as a separate OS? Which version of Ubuntu did you install? Please add this useful information by clicking [edit].

Answer (score 1):

I had to install another file browser (Thundar file Manager) and it worked. Apparently the default file manager just doesn't like dealing with the Windows folder.